# Altium: Vias not showing annular ring

Tags: pcb-design, altium

I have vias connected to the polygon. In the old design (left pic) the vias have annular rings. But I modified few other things in the PCB. I removed unused vias in both new and old design. But now in the new one (right picture) the vias don't have the rings showing up. I guess, it doesn't make difference for the manufacturer? But also, I don't know why is it happening.

[image]

Comment: Please show the properties window for the problem vias. Also, is the copper surrounding them on the same or a different net from the vias? Also, are  both types actually vias, or is one of these structures a pad (as defined by Altium)? What are your polygon connection rules for vias and for pads?

Answer (score 2):

If you check off “tented” in the via properties on the relevant side the solder mask will not be pulled back around the via, so it will look different in both the layout and when it is fabricated.

See, for example, [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/453644/via-tenting-when-solder-masking-an-entire-layer-on-altium?rq=1) answer.

There are various reasons to prefer one over the other, but that’s outside the scope of this answer.

Comment: This is internal layer. Vias are tented in both old and new design.

Comment: Are the padstacks for the vias identical?

Comment: Yes. The are simple vias. I only removed the unused pads from Altium. But I was on both old and new design. It seems like some setting in Altium to me.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue and found the solution here after some digging: [Greyed out vias in altium](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/524933/greyed-out-vias-in-altium)

The solution is:
Tools >> Remove Unused Pad Shapes >> Scope = Both(vias in this case) , Operation = Restore Unused

Not sure what caused this issue initially but now all my vias have annular rings on all layers again.